# PHP Checking if a string starts with #

Tags: php, string

I know theres functions for this but the ones i've tried wont work with the character '#'
The one im using right now is

```
function startsWithChar($needle, $haystack)
{
   return ($needle[0] === $haystack);
}
```

and it returns false when I try to check for '#'.

Does anyone know a function that works with the '#' character?

**EDIT:**
I noticed that the function works, the problem is that I'm trying to do this using GET. Apparantly the string gets ignored when a GET begins with # (search.php?query=#asd). Do you know a workaround for this?

Comment: how do you know it returns false with #?

Comment: you're mixing terms though. It should be `$haystack[0] === $needle`. Haystack is where we search and needle is what we search

Comment: If the URL ends in `#asd` then PHP will never see it. The browser filters out the hash/anchor name. The $_GET variable will be empty, and this is why it failed. You have to `urlencode()` the `#` if you want to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you confusing your needle and your haystack?

```
function startsWithChar($needle, $haystack) {
    return ($haystack[0] === $needle);
}

$string1 = 'Test';
var_dump(startsWithChar('#',$string1)) ;

$string2 = '#Test';
var_dump(startsWithChar('#',$string2)) ;
```

Comment: I changed place with them and it still returns false so thats not the issue.

Comment: @Krufts - show us the data you're working with. This method works, as long as your string really does begin with a # character. var_dump your needle and haystack before the test to confirm.

Comment: I noticed that the function works, the problem is that I'm trying to do this using GET. Apparantly the string gets ignored when a GET begins with # (search.php?query=#asd). Do you know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've edited, it all becomes clear. The literal '#' character in the URL is interpreted as the end of the query string and the start of the fragment, so your script is getting just "search.php?query=". Use %23 instead. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent_encoding for details.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function startsWithChar($haystack, $needle){
    return mb_strpos($haystack, $needle) === 1;
}
```